# Are PHP PECL extentions on Cloud9 working?

Tags: php, httprequest, httpresponse, cloud9-ide, pecl

I wanted to test some basic http_request functions (ie: `echo http_request(HTTP_METH_GET,"http://www.example.com");`) but PECL extensions dont seem to be working in Cloud9's IDE. Which is strange because the code hints show http_request and http_response_code are both available making it seem as if PECL extentions are installed. Is there a trick that i'm missing? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install these packages first:

```
sudo apt-get install php-http
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl3
sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
sudo pecl install raphf 
sudo pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6
```

Then change your php.ini configuration (add lines with "extension" and change enable_dl from Off to On):

```
enable_dl = On
extension = raphf.so
extension = propro.so
extension = hash.so
extension = iconv.so
extension = json.so
extension = http.so
```

Then stop and start project and PECL/HTTP should be working correct.

I tried this code and works fine:

```
$r = new HttpRequest('http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$r->addQueryData(array('category' => 3));
$r->send();
if ($r->getResponseCode() == 200)
    print $r->getResponseBody();
```

Comment: So that does the trick but I cant access any of the methods of httprequest. I have to use the &$info array. Is that by design or a limitation of Cloud9??

Comment: @JohnR I added to answer code which I succefully run in Cloud9